# Use of moved value when pattern matching an enum with multiple values after downcasting

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I can use pattern matching on an `enum` that has one `String` parameter:

```
extern crate robots;

use std::any::Any;
use robots::actors::{Actor, ActorCell};

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum ExampleMessage {
    Msg { param_a: String },
}

pub struct Dummy {}

impl Actor for Dummy {
    // Using `Any` is required for actors in RobotS
    fn receive(&self, message: Box<Any>, _context: ActorCell) {
        if let Ok(message) = Box::<Any>::downcast::<ExampleMessage>(message) {
            match *message {
                ExampleMessage::Msg { param_a } => println!("got message"),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yet I am unable to perform pattern matching on an enum with 2 parameters:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum ExampleMessage {
    Msg { param_a: String, param_b: usize },
}

impl Actor for Dummy {
    // Using `Any` is required for actors in RobotS
    fn receive(&self, message: Box<Any>, _context: ActorCell) {
        if let Ok(message) = Box::<Any>::downcast::<ExampleMessage>(message) {
            match *message {
                ExampleMessage::Msg { param_a, param_b } => println!("got message"),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `message`
  --> src/example.rs:19:48
   |
19 |                 ExampleMessage::Msg { param_a, param_b } => {
   |                                       -------  ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |                                       |
   |                                       value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because `message.param_a` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I tried pattern matching on the same `enum` without downcasting before, and this works fine but I am required to downcast.
This just seems like very strange behavior to me and I don't know how to circumvent this error.

I am using Rust 1.19.0-nightly (afa1240e5 2017-04-29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried pattern matching on the same enum without downcasting before, and this works fine

This is a good attempt at reducing the problem. The issue is that you reduced too far. Downcasting a `Box<T>` to a `Foo` doesn't return a `Foo`, [it returns a `Box<Foo>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast):

```
fn downcast<T>(self) -> Result<Box<T>, Box<Any + 'static>>
```

You can reproduce the problem with:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum ExampleMessage {
    Msg { param_a: String, param_b: usize },
}

fn receive2(message: Box<ExampleMessage>) {
    match *message {
        ExampleMessage::Msg { param_a, param_b } => println!("got message"),
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

#### The good news

This is a limitation of the current implementation of the borrow checker and your original code will work as-is when [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) are enabled:

```
#![feature(nll)]

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum ExampleMessage {
    Msg { param_a: String, param_b: usize },
}

fn receive2(message: Box<ExampleMessage>) {
    match *message {
        ExampleMessage::Msg { param_a, param_b } => println!("got message"),
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

#### The current reality

Non-lexical lifetimes and the MIR-based borrow checker are not yet stable!

When you match against a dereferenced value, the value is *not* normally moved. This [allows you to do something like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43370054/155423):

```
enum Foo {
    One,
    Two,
}

fn main() {
    let f = &Foo::One;
    match *f {
        Foo::One => {}
        Foo::Two => {}
    }
}
```

In this case, you wish to take ownership of the thing inside the `Box`<sup>1</sup> in order to take ownership of the fields when destructuring it in the `match`. You can accomplish this by moving the value out of the box *before* trying to match on it.

The long way to do this is:

```
fn receive2(message: Box<ExampleMessage>) {
    let message = *message;
    match message {
        ExampleMessage::Msg { param_a, param_b } => println!("got message"),
    }
}
```

But you can also force the move by using curly braces:

```
fn receive2(message: Box<ExampleMessage>) {
    match {*message} {
        ExampleMessage::Msg { param_a, param_b } => println!("got message"),
    }
}
```

I don't fully understand why a single field would work; it's certainly inconsistent. My only *guess* is that the ownership of the `Box` is moved to the first param, the param is extracted, then the compiler tries to move it again to the next parameter.

---

**1** — Moving the contained element out via `*` is a special power that only `Box` supports. For example, if you try to do this with a reference, you get the "cannot move out of borrowed content" error. You cannot implement the `Deref` trait to do this either; it's a hard-coded ability inside the compiler.

Comment: I'm having a very hard time fixing up my mental model here...what is wrong with your original version of `receive2`?  And why does the problem disappear when binding only a single struct field?  Does it have something to do with `Box<>` being special?  Also -- what special power are you referring to?  Thanks Shep

Comment: @user1935361 I added a little bit more text.

Comment: in regards to [1] -- because `Deref` always returns a reference, I think I get it.