# How to match on an Option inside an Arc?

Tags: rust

The [docs for `Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#deref-behavior) say:

> `Arc<T>` automatically dereferences to `T` (via the `Deref` trait), so you can call `T`'s methods on a value of type `Arc<T>`.

But is there any way to allow for matching on `Option`-al types?

Here is a simple example:

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let foo: Arc<Option<String>> = Arc::new(Some("hello".to_string()));

    if foo.is_some() {
        println!("{}", foo.unwrap());
    }

    match foo {
        Some(hello) => {
            println!("{}", hello);
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         Some(hello) => {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::sync::Arc`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::sync::Arc<std::option::Option<std::string::String>>`
              found type `std::option::Option<_>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 |         None => {}
   |         ^^^^ expected struct `std::sync::Arc`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::sync::Arc<std::option::Option<std::string::String>>`
              found type `std::option::Option<_>`
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot match on an `Option` inside of an `Arc`. To use a type in pattern matching, the implementation of the type must be available to you, but the implementation of `Arc` is not public.

---

In certain cases, you can perform some kind of conversion to be able to match on a *reference*.

For example, since `Arc<T>` implements `Deref`, you can use the `*` operator to dereference through the `Arc<T>` to the underlying `T`. Since there's [some ergonomic syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43370054/155423) for this kind of matching, you can then take a reference to the value inside the `Option` without taking ownership of it:

```
match *foo {
    Some(ref hello) => {
        println!("{}", hello);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

You can also use `Option::as_ref` to convert the `&Option<T>` ([automatically dereferenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423) from the `Arc<T>` via `Deref`) to an `Option<&T>`:

```
match Option::as_ref(&foo) {
    Some(hello) => {
        println!("{}", hello);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't just call `.as_ref()` because the trait method `AsRef::as_ref` takes precedence.

In both cases, it's more idiomatic to use `if let` if you only care about one of the match arms:

```
if let Some(ref hello) = *foo {
    println!("{}", hello);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first `println` passed the early stages of the compiler, but it got flagged by the borrow checker in a later stage.  The second `println` was an easier fix.

```
use std::sync::Arc;

fn main() {
    let foo: Arc<Option<String>> = Arc::new(Some("hello".to_string()));

    if foo.is_some() {
        let f1: &Option<String> = foo.as_ref();
        let f2: Option<&String> = f1.as_ref();
        let f3: &String = f2.unwrap();
        println!("{}", f3);

        println!("{}", foo.as_ref().as_ref().unwrap())
    }

    match *foo {
        Some(ref hello) => {
            println!("{}", hello);
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

The first `println` confusingly uses two `as_ref()` method calls.  The first `as_ref` acts on the `Arc`, with type signature `Fn(&Arc<Option<String>>) -> &Option<String>`.  The second one acts on the `Option`, with type signature `Fn(&Option<String>) -> Option<&String>`

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a428e8470e9a46eadcea800bb5b75fe3&version=stable)

Comment: Dereferencing `foo` (as in `let f2 = (*foo).as_ref()`)is a little more idiomatic than using `.as_ref` on an `Arc`.